# How to create a listener that's listening to multiple shortcuts Ctrl + [1-9]?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

### Question

How do I create a listener that's listening to multiple shortcuts Ctrl + [1-9] and then passes the pressed shortcut value to the `changeRoute (pressedNumber)` method?

### For example

- `Ctrl + 1` is pressed
- `changeRoute (pressedNumber)` displays `1` in the console
- `Ctrl + 2` is pressed
- `changeRoute (pressedNumber)` displays `2` in the console
- ... etc

### Code (vue.js)

So far I have this:

```js
created () {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', this.switchTab)
},

methods: {
  switchTab (event) {
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 49) {
     this.changeRoute (event)        
    }

    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 50) {
     this.changeRoute (event)        
    }
    ...
  },
  changeRoute (event) {
    console.log(event.key)
  }
}
```

How do I avoid 9 `if` statements?

## UPDATE:

I've resolved the issue in the following way:

```
if ((event.key >= 1 && event.key <= 9) && event.ctrlKey == true) {
  let tabPathIndex = event.key - 1
}
```

Comment: @Kaiido could you please give an example? I don't know how to pass the pressed value to the method (btw I only need it to work in the latest Chrome)

Comment: Hmm sorry I might have misread. Could you clarify the problem a bit more? Do you have issues to call the `changeRoute` method from `switchTab` as an handler?  You will have to bind it when attaching it  (`addEventListener('keydown', this.switchTab.bind(this))`). Or do you have issues in getting [keyCode = 49] => [index = 1]?

Comment: @Kaiido ahh, I see. I just did this `this.switchTab.bind(this)` and console.log() the value in `switchTab(event)` I can see that it shows me the `key: "1"` but the problem is if I press `ctrl + 2` the method doesn't run. How do I make sure it runs any time `ctrl + [1-9]` is pressed and not just when ctrl + 1 is pressed (which is now specified as `event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode === 49`) do I just do it with a loop?

Comment: I'm going to update the question to clarify

Comment: You want only 1~9 ? Then `if(+event.key >= 1 && +event.key<=9)` would do in modern browsers. (note that some layout don't map to the same keys though (e.g AZERTY keyboards would actually require ctrl + shift + & to produce `key:"1"`). If you want only the physical key, you might have to use the old `evt.keyCode<=49 && evt.keyCode <= 57)`

Comment: @Kaiido yeah, sorry for the confusion. This seems to work fine`(event.ctrlKey && +event.key >= 1 && +event.key <= 9)`. I just had to pass the event. Thanks for the info. If you post the answer I'm gonna accept it

Answer (score 3):

`F1-F9` keys are in a **range** of possible numerals, so just use that range in a single `if` statement:

```
created () {
  window.addEventListener('keydown', this.switchTab)
},

methods: {
  switchTab (event) {
    // F1 = 112, F12 = 123 
    if (event.ctrlKey && event.keyCode > 111 && event.keyCode < 124   ) {
     this.changeRoute (event)        
    }
  },
  changeRoute (event) {
    console.log(event.key)
  }
}
```

## Vanilla JS demo:

```js
   // Try pressing CTRL+F1 to F12 (give the demo window focus first)
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
    console.log( e.keyCode );
    return false;
})
```

Comment: Thanks, I need the numbers not the F keys, but that also works. It didn't occur to me I could just specify the range. Probably should't code at night -_-

Comment: Yeah yeah, I did. `keyCode  == 49` to `keyCode  == 57` do the trick

Comment: Though I noticed that if you release the `ctrl` before a `number` key is released then it's not getting triggered. Is there a way prevent this? Normally it should be triggered on keydown, but it waits for the `keyup`

Comment: Doesn't make sense, because the event is a `keydown` event, so it fires when a key is pressed, and not released, so as long as there was a moment in time where both keys were pressed together, the event should fire. what OS/browser you're using?

Comment: I'm on windows 10, (chrome 66). It only triggers if I hold `ctrl` all the way.  If I release `ctrl` before the `number` key is `Up` then it's not getting triggered

Comment: Even in the demo I've made in the answer this happens to you? I'm on `windows 7/Chrome 66` also and it's working as expected

Answer (score 1):

if you wan't to still be explicit, you could use a `switch` statement:

```
if(event.ctrlKey) {
    switch(event.keyCode) {
        case 49: case 50: case 51: case 52: case 53: 
        case 54: case 55: case 56: case 57: case 58:
            this.changeRoute(event);
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that works too. I've settled with this: `if ((event.key >= 1 && event.key <= 9) && event.ctrlKey == true) { }`